# Forms with fields of type "file" aren't being submitted to server due to "MultipartException: The current request is not a multipart request"

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, multipartform-data

In my current spring-boot project, I have this configuration for MultipartFile in my main Application class:

```
  @Bean
  MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
    MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
    factory.setMaxFileSize("128KB");
    factory.setMaxRequestSize("128KB");
    return factory.createMultipartConfig();
  }
```

my form have this format:

```
<form role="form" class="form" action="/Categoria/cadastra" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
</form>
```

in my controller, the handler for this request is this method:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "cadastra", method=RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public void cadastra(@ModelAttribute("object") E object, BindingResult result, @RequestParam(value="icone", required=false) MultipartFile icone, @RequestParam(value="fotos", required=false) MultipartFile fotos[]) {
    ...
  }
```

but when I try submit data from the form, I am getting this error:

```
MultipartException: The current request is not a multipart request
org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.assertIsMultipartRequest(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:216)
org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.resolveName(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:167)
org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:89)
org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:157)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:124)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1695)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Anyone can tell me how to solve this?

**UPDATE**

I have tried this other way:

Application.java:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

application.properties:

```
# Multipart configuration
multipart.fileSizeThreshold = 131072
multipart.location = ${user.home}/.mystore/uploads
multipart.maxFileSize = -1
multipart.maxRequestSize = -1
```

this don't work as well. Anyone have a useful hint of what is wrong with this code?

**UPDATE 2**

I don't if this have anything with the issue, but when I check the browser's network console tool, I notice none of the `input[type=file]` fields are listed as parameters of the request, despite the fact all of them should be present (all have a attribute `name` on it).

**UPDATE 3**

I try solve this issue using a external lib, jquery.form, changing my code to this:

```
$("form.form").ajaxForm(function(data){
    if(data == "") {
        $("#yes").show();
    } else {
        var $temp  = $('<div/>', {html:data});
        $("#not").find(".text").empty();
        $("#not").find(".text").html( $temp.remove('head').html() );
        $("#not").show();
    }
});
```

It works, but now I am looking for a solution which don't requires add a extra jquery lib to my project.

Comment: Have you added 'multipartResolver' bean to your spring configuration?

Comment: Work with the framework, not around it. Use the [Spring Boot properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-multipart-file-upload-configuration) in the `application.properties` to enable multipart file uploads. And remove your own configuration.

Comment: @Sudarshan_SMD yes, I add the multipartResolver I post above in my Application  class.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am following exactly what the official site suggests, in this link: http://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/.

Comment: Read the documentation, not the guides. You don't need to add that bean...

Comment: @M.Deinum I change my code to try the way suggested by the link you indicate me, too. Same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess there is problem with `application.properties` configuration. You have set `maxFileSize` and `maxRequestSize` to -1. I am not sure if this is correct.

Read [this guide page](http://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/) to know how file upload is done in spring boot application.

**UPDATE:**
If your form contains both `file` content and `textfields` to be submitted to server side, you should create a domain class having attributes named same as form elements. And submit complete form to server side, get all the form data in `@ModelAttribute`. Now `ModelAttribute` will have both files and textfields as well. Sample code for your reference:

Following is the `DTO` class to carry form data:

```
public class PartDetailsDto {
    private String PartId;
    private MultipartFile productImage;
    private MultipartFile approvalLetter;
}
```

Following is the `Controller` method :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "parts/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createPart(@ModelAttribute("partInfo") PartDetailsDto partDetails) {
    // Here in partDetails you will get form data
}
```

And JSP form would be something like this:

```
<form autocomplete="off" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/parts/create" method="POST" name="partInfo" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    // here you will have text fields and file content
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

Using JQuery file upload in the client side that is multipart and adding this code on the server side works like a charm.

```
   /**
 * File upload by JQuery Upload file
 *
 * @param defaultMultipartHttpServletRequest
 *
 * @param id
 * @return
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFiles", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Map uploadFiles(MultipartHttpServletRequest defaultMultipartHttpServletRequest,
```

Did you try MultipartHttpServletRequest on the server side?.

On the client side JQuery file upload looks like.

```
function initializeFileUpload() {
$("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
    url: 'url',
    dragDrop: true,
    multiple: true,
    autoSubmit: true,
    showStatusAfterSuccess: false,
    showAbort: false,
    showDone: false,
    maxFileSize: MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE,
    fileName: 'fileData',
    uploadButtonClass: 'btn btn-primary col-xs-3',
    onSuccess: function (files, data, xhr) {
    showStatus(callbackAction.ERROR);

    }
});
```

Comment: the problem is my form have both type of fields (text and file). I need a solution which allow me submit both types of data once.

Comment: I have the same situation but I believe is not possible do that.